# .NET Prometheus max limit for counters

Tags: .net, .net-core, prometheus

When using counters in prometheus for .NET, would we ever hit the problem of reaching the max limit for the counter (assuming the application never restarts) . If so, would it be taken care by prometheus? As in Counter I can see double type for value “public double Value => _value.Value;”

would it be taken care by prometheus?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you are asking about? You anticipate something like 1.8e308 value for your counter?